# Некорректно отображается текст

Tags: python

Текст в файле отображается некорректно.

```
f = open("Безназвания.txt", "r")
for line in f:
     print(line)
```

Текст в "Безназвания.txt":

```
Hello, world!
some text
```

Но отображается:

```
Hello, WorldHello, World!

some text
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В текстовом файле всякая строка окончена символом перехода на новую строку: `"\n"`

Функция `print()` добавит стандартно тоже символ `"\n"` - значит, будут 2 такие знаки подряд и на выводе окажется пустая строка.

При загрузке из файла нужно этот символ убрать, например так - и я для вас напишу более удобный подход для открытия (и неявного закрытия) файла:

```
with open("Безназвания.txt") as f:        # "r" не нужно
    for line in f:
        print(line[:-1])                  # line[:-1] исключит последний знак, т.е. "\n"
```

Другое решение — применить метод `.rstrip()` для удаления всех пустых символов из конца строки (т.е. пробелов, табуляторов и символов `"\n"`):

```
with open("Безназвания.txt") as f:        # "r" не нужно
    for line in f:
        print(line.rstrip())              # удалит все пустые символы из конца строки
```

Answer (score 0):

А вообще для вывода содержимого файла куда проще использовать:

```
file_data = open('test.txt','r').read()
print(file_data)
```